# discord.py send embed message from source code

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So I was trying to make embed command. Code:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def embed(ctx):
    def check(message):
        return message.author == ctx.author and message.channel == ctx.channel

    await ctx.send('Send me your source code.')
    source = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
    src = source.content
  
    await ctx.send(embed=src)
```

And yeah I am wondering is there a way to convert this string to `discord.Embed`. I really want to send embed using source code.

Answer (score 1):

What you got is a string which you can't send as an embed like this.

As you said, you have to put this into an [embed](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#embed).

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def embed(ctx):
    def check(message):
        return message.author == ctx.author and message.channel == ctx.channel

    await ctx.send('Send me your source code.')
    source = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)

    embed = discord.Embed(title="Custom Embed", description=source.content, colour=discord.Colour.red())
    # You can put the colour to whatever you want with 0xHEXCODE (e.g. 0x30F90)
  
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```